# htaccess rewrite parameters single page + iframe

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iframe, url-rewriting

I've been through plenty of docs but can't find the right rule on this case.

I have a single index.php file, containing a single iframe.php.

There is 3 optional parameters, although the first two have defaults if not specified. The parameters are passed to the iframe.

So I have

```
domain.com/?lang=en&country=us&game=myId
```

The iframe is called within the index like so :

```
<iframe src="iframe.php?lang=en&country=us&game=myId">
```

I would like the URL to be rewritten as :

```
domain.com/en-us/myId
```

without messing up the iframe parameters.

**But**

If the page is called without language parameters, the defaults are still set in the iframe, calling

```
domain.com
```

gives

```
<iframe src="iframe.php?lang=en&country=us">
```

In this case I would like the main URL to display

```
domain.com/en-us
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /en-us [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*)|)$ /iframe.php?lang=$1&country=$2&game=$3 [L,QSA]
```

You then need to make sure you are constructing your URL's like:

```
domain.com/en-us/myId
```

and not use the query strings.

If you need to redirect the browser when accessing pages using query strings, include:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /iframe.php\?lang=([a-z]{2})&country=([a-z]{2})(?:&([^&\ ]+))($|&|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2/%3 [L,R=301]
```

---

To create separate rules for 2 and 3 parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ /iframe.php?lang=$1&country=$2&game=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/?$ /iframe.php?lang=$1&country=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your first example works perfectly for the 2 first parameters, but not for the last one. Looks like it's added even though the parameter is not present (iframe is called whith ?lang=XX&country=XX&game=).

Comment: @kursus it's either that or you need to create a rule for each, one for 2 params, and one for 3 params

Comment: Ok now that makes sense. Last thing it does not seems to work when a trailer slash is added after the language parameters (domain.com/en-us/), thus making the game parameter not working as well. Is it the rule or my code ?

Comment: Precision : the iframe parameters are set with PHP GET based upon index parameters, so I replaced iframe with index in the rules you gave me.

Comment: @kursus the `?` at the end of the rule, right after the `/`, says that the last `/` is optional. So it will match both `/en-us` and `/en-us/`. Not sure why that isn't working.

Comment: I got it, as soon as /en-us/ is added, the path for my assets becomes "en-us/assets" instead of "assets". All my paths are relatively coded. I tried with RewriteBase / but no luck. Any options apart absolute paths ?

Comment: @kursus the `RewriteBase` only affects rewrite rules, not how the browser determines what a relative URL's base should be. To set a base for the browser, add a tag like this to the header of your pages: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Yes I just found this, everything is ok now. Thank you VERY much kind stranger.